# Extract information from forecasting object into separate data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop, forecasting

I am foresting with a forecasting function from the `forecast` package and also I use an accuracy function from the same package. Output are several objects (class matrix) but I want to focus with files with the names `ERROR_Electricity` and `ERROR_Cement`. You can see code below :

```
#  CODE
    library(fpp2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(forecast)
    library(tidyr)
    library(stringr)

    #INPUT DATA
    mydata_qauselec <- qauselec
    mydata_qcement <- window(qcement, start = 1956, end = c(2010, 2))

    # Мerging data
    mydata <- cbind(mydata_qauselec, mydata_qcement)
    colnames(mydata) <- c("Electricity", "Cement")

    # Test Extract Name
    mydata1 <- data.frame(mydata)
    COL_NAMES <- names(mydata1)
    rm(mydata_qauselec, mydata_qcement)

    # FORCASTING HORIZON
    forecast_horizon <- 12

    # FORECASTING
    for(i in 1:ncol(mydata)){
      # Build a ts for this column
      timeseries <- msts(mydata[,i], start = 1956, seasonal.periods = c(4))
      # Build a foreacst based on the ts
      forecast <- snaive(timeseries, biasadj = TRUE, h =  forecast_horizon)
      accuracy_results <- accuracy(forecast)
      residuals_snaive <- Box.test(zoo::na.approx(forecast$residuals), type = "Ljung") 
      # rename the forecast according to the original variable name
      colname <- colnames(mydata)[i]
      #FORECASTING SETS
      forecastName <- paste("SNAIVE_", colname," <- forecast", sep = "")
      eval(parse(text = forecastName))
      #EVALUATION SET
      forecastName1 <- paste("ERROR_", colname," <- accuracy_results", sep="")
      eval(parse(text = forecastName1))
      #RESIDUALS SET
      forecastName2 <- paste("RESIDUALS_", colname," <- residuals_snaive", sep  "")
      eval(parse(text = forecastName2))
    }
```

So my intention here is to put objects `ERROR_Electricity` and `ERROR_Cement`, into `DF_TABLE` in an automated way. So code is need to find this two objects which names start with `ERROR_` and put into the data frame `DF_TABLE`. This is very important to me because this is only a test with a small example, a normal example maybe have 5 or 10 objects which the name will started with `ERROR_`. Below you can see some example but intention is to do on automated way not with specification in brackets (`ERROR_Electricity`, `ERROR_Cement`) like example below.

```
DF_TABLE <- data.frame(rbind(ERROR_Electricity, ERROR_Cement))
```

So can anybody help me with this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use R-functionals approach with `apply()` family. To make things a little easier let's wrap your forecast run into a separate function:

```
BuildForecast <- function(Z, hrz = forecast_horizon) {
  timeseries <- msts(Z, start = 1956, seasonal.periods = 4)
  forecast <- snaive(timeseries, biasadj = TRUE, h =  hrz)
}
```

Then we may use `lapply()` to easily obtain a list of the forecasts for each column of the `mydata1` data frame:

```
frc_list <- lapply(X = mydata1, BuildForecast)
```

The same approach works to extract the accuracy and the residuals:

```
res_accur <- lapply(frc_list,  accuracy)
# forecast::residuals() is a built-in function to extract the residuals values
res_resid <- lapply(frc_list, 
  function(Z) Box.test(zoo::na.approx(residuals(Z)), type = "Ljung"))
```

The output of `lapply()` is a list. If you need a more compact structure, you can bind the results like this:

```
res_accur_v <- do.call(rbind, res_accur)
```

or use `vapply()`:

```
res_resid_v <- vapply(frc_list, 
  function(Z) unlist(Box.test(zoo::na.approx(residuals(Z)), type = "Ljung")),
  character(5))
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @silent_hunter Glad to help :)

Comment: I have some additional questions about this, so please check if you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693208/automatically-plots-with-autoplot-function-from-forecasting-object